# Is there a way to use VFP SQL syntax when using ADS OLEDB for VFP?

Tags: foxpro, advantage-database-server

- Sample connection string
  Provider=Advantage.OLEDB.1;Data Source=c:\Bugtest;ServerType=ADS_LOCAL_SERVER; TableType=ADS_VFP_TABLE

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately no, the SQL is passed directly to Advantage, which uses its own parser, not the VFP parser. Good suggestion though (supporting the syntax). You could add it to the feedback site at http://feedback.advantagedatabase.com